# JScrollBar adjustment issue

Tags: java, jscrollbar

I am having an issue with my horizontal scroll bar demo. I am trying to move a custom message panel using the scroll bar. I used an anonymous listener and override the adjustmentValueChanged() method like so,

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
   System.out.println(e.getAdjustmentType());
   if( e.getAdjustmentType() == AdjustmentEvent.UNIT_INCREMENT ) {
      panel.moveLeft();
   }
}
```

I am trying to get the AdjustmentEvent using e.getAdjustmentType() so I can properly handle the adjustment of the message panel. However, it is not working. I used System.out.println() method to print the adjustment type on my screen to see what the problem is but what I am not understanding is that no matter what part of the scroll bar I press (whether it is the unit increment, unit decrement, block increment, etc..) the value returned is 5? I am not sure what the issue is can someone please help.

```
public class ScrollBarDemo extends JFrame {

   private JScrollBar scrollHort = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
   private JScrollBar scrollVert = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
   private MessagePanel panel = new MessagePanel("Welcom to Java bitch");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ScrollBarDemo frame = new ScrollBarDemo();
      frame.setTitle("ScrollBarDemo");
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public ScrollBarDemo() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(scrollHort, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      add(scrollVert, BorderLayout.EAST);
      scrollHort.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
         public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getAdjustmentType());
            if (e.getAdjustmentType() == AdjustmentEvent.UNIT_INCREMENT) {
               panel.moveLeft();
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a JScrollPane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am trying to practice using JScrollBar so this is just a demo for me to understand the events this component fires.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following sample, the method to use is [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/AdjustmentEvent.html#getValue--).

```
public class ScrollBarDemo extends JFrame {

   public ScrollBarDemo() {
      setLayout( new BorderLayout());
      final JScrollBar scrollHort = new JScrollBar( JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL );
      add( scrollHort, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
      scrollHort.addAdjustmentListener( e -> System.out.println( e.getValue()));
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      new ScrollBarDemo();
   }
}
```